# My winlogbeat logs only see 6kb, not sure what my settings should be?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, logging, virtual-machine, virtual

I am trying to get my Sysmon data to winlogbeat and then to security onion.
I am having two issues.
1 – the winlogbeat logs where being fed continually, but now it is on getting the initial service start data.
2 – I cannot seem to get my Sysmon data into security onion kibana.

I dont know how to include the the actual yml files. It says i exceeded how much i can put in this post. But i believe it is in there.

thanks for any help or advice, especially about how i can give you my yml files.

Comment: Maybe you could give us the input and output of the `filebeat.yml` ? With out details we can't really help.

Comment: thanks for responding. One problem is that i dont know how to send the winlogbeat.yml, sysmonconfig-export.xml because they are to large to include in the post. Please let me know how to do that? And i didnt know that i needed a filebeat.yml?

I was wondering where those filebeat entries in my security onion Hunt and kibana tools, but not my sysmon info?

Comment: my bad `winlogbeat.yml` is what we need.

Only include the relevant part of those file.

Comment: i believe these are the relative info :

Comment: i believe these are the relative info :    winlogbeat.event_logs:
  - name: Application
    ignore_older: 72h
  - name: System

  - name: Security
  - name: Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational
  - name: Windows PowerShell
    event_id: 400, 403, 600, 800
  - name: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational
    event_id: 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106
  - name: ForwardedEvents
    tags: [forwarded]

Comment: # ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  #enabled: true

  # The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["192.168.0.0/16:5044"]

Comment: not really sure about what ip and port i should be telneting?

Comment: Please add them in the question. This is not really readable

Comment: I see now why my logs only contain  6kb of data. When I looked at the Current winlogbeat service parms.

"D:\vm workstation\winlogbeat\winlogbeat.exe" --environment=windows_service -c "D:\vm workstation\winlogbeat\winlogbeat.yml" --path.home "D:\vm workstation\winlogbeat" --path.data "C:\ProgramData\winlogbeat" --path.logs "C:\ProgramData\winlogbeat\logs" -E logging.files.redirect_stderr=true.

Comment: This is why all the log data went to the programdata folder and not my vm workstation folder.

I need to be sending my path.data and path.logs to  "D:\vm workstation\winlogbeat" and not "C:\ProgramData\winlogbeat\logs".  I am trying to google what the syntax is to changes these paths in my winlogbeat.yml?